# Statamic - How can I access assets and single assets with attributes?

Tags: assets, statamic

In statamic, I have a container with images defined, and attributes set on those images. I then save a single asset page variable in page/index.md

```
photo: assets/main/image.jpg
```

I can use the method below, but only if I create a single image fieldset for the page, which is tedious.

```
{{ asset:photo }}
    {{ glide src="{{ url }}" alt="{{ alt }}" />
{{ /asset:photo }}

{{ asset:photo }}
    <img src="{{ value }}" alt="{{ alt }}" />
{{ /asset:photo }}
```

I can also make a container and put the single image in the container to access like below, but that is also tedious.

```
{{ assets container="photo" }}
    <img src="{{ glide:id height="44" fit="crop_focal" }}" alt="{{ alt }}" />
{{ /assets }}
```

What is the best way to access single assets with their attributes without creating a container or fieldset every time? Bonus if I can also use glide to manipulate the image!

I resorted to using the below method, but cannot access any attributes this way.

```
<img src="{{ glide:photo height='44' fit='resize' }}" alt="Have to enter this attribute manually" />
```

Comment: I thought i could help but a re-read makes me unsure i fully understand.
If this is a matter of markup efficiency( _lazyness_ ;) ) , i can share a partial from which to build upon.  
However, the portion about the Container strikes me that i'm not fully understanding the scenario, or, that you're creating a separate asset container in place of a field on a fieldset  which is a sort of _code-smell_ at the implementation level.   Care to elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I can save an asset, title, and alt text in the GUI. What is the shortest way to put that asset and its alt text into the statamic page?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need:

Create an Asset field type, for this example, we can name it `featured_image`. Then set the `max_files` to 1.

In your Antlers template, call it like this:

```
<img src="{{ featured_image }}" alt="{{ alt }}">
```

or

```
<img src="{{ featured_image:permalink }}" alt="{{ alt }}">
```

I hope this helps anyone struggling with it.